# What does *= mean in Python? From this Codecademy assignement

Tags: python, operators

```
def tax(bill):
    """Adds 8% tax to a restaurant bill."""
    bill *= 1.08
    print "With tax: %f" % bill
    return bill

def tip(bill):
    """Adds 15% tip to a restaurant bill."""
    bill *= 1.15
    print "With tip: %f" % bill
    return bill

meal_cost = 100
meal_with_tax = tax(meal_cost)
meal_with_tip = tip(meal_with_tax)
```

As you can see next to bill it says bill *= 1.08. I searched google but just got "Your search - *= - did not match any documents."

Comment: Do you know what `+=` does? What would you expect that to do?

Answer (score 3):

It just a short term of,

```
bill = bill * 1.08
```

Example:

```
>>> bill = 1.23
>>> bill *= 1.08
>>> bill
1.3284
>>> bill = 1.23
>>> bill = bill * 1.08
>>> bill
1.3284
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bill *= 1.15
```

is the same as writing

```
bill = bill * 1.15
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called an assignment operator. It multiplies right operand with the left operand and assigns the result to the left operand.